# Multisite: Activate plugin for subsites only?

Tags: plugins, multisite, activation

For some plugins, I'm trying to activate only for subsites.
Lets say the plugin is "Contact Form 7" and I need it activated only on subsites.

If activate on Network Admin, it will activated on main site as well.

*I've came across many reference but it is old article (5 years ago) and only teaching how to make multisite compatible plugin and not subsites-only plugin.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, most of plugins work exactly the way you want:

- You MUST upload them (i.e. install them) on network admin panel, but
  you can leave them deactivated.
- Then, you go to an individual subsite plugin page and activate only
  for said subsite.